# jQuery.on('follow') event?

Tags: jquery

What's the appropriate way of a "link follow" event?

```
<a href="#" class="link">link</a>
<script>$('.link').on('click', function() { });</script>
```

Capturing the click event is not enough, because you can follow the link also by using double click or hitting the enter key.

Instead of wrapping each possible event, is there a ready-to-go function like `on('follow')`?

Comment: The `click` event fires even if the link was activated by keypress: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Le4pd48s/, the link is focused by default simply press enter to see the event hook working.

Comment: So in which case are you encountering issue binding click event?

Comment: There's no such event, and it's not possible to reliably know if a link was followed by using one of the many ways to open a link (right click, left click, control click, etc. etc.)

Comment: Note that if you want to execute a function on click *or* double click you'll have to programmatically distinguish very well between them. If you don't, double click will merely be seen as two subsequent click events, which will in turn call the click event twice.

Comment: @adeneo Ya the hard way seems to handle link followed through the context menu **and** accesskey

Comment: You should edit your question because both of your examples `double click or hitting the enter key` are wrong, both fire the click event

Comment: what is the purpose to follow? i don't get it guys can anyone update me on it. **is it like navigating away?**

Comment: @Jai If an user e.g use contextmenu on anchor to follow a link, OP wants to get an event fired, i guess... `contextmenu` wouldn't be enough in this case because user could still not follow link

Comment: you can see if the key used was mouse or enter, for example.. http://jsfiddle.net/v2wvF/

Comment: Thanks for this ton of feedback, I wasn't aware that `click` event gets fired even when using enter key to follow a link!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem using a `semaphore`. The `semaphore` should turn to green after a certain amount of time, say, 100 milliseconds. Let's suppose you have a function like this:

```
function onFollow(params) {
    //do something
}
```

Let's suppose further that you have an initialization, like

```
var semaphore = true;
var time = 100; //for example
```

You need to have a `function` like this:

```
function invalidEvent(e) {
    semaphore = false;
    setTimeout(function() {
        semaphore = true;
    }, time);
}
```

Let's have something like this:

```
$('.link').on('click', function(e) {
    //initialize params and maybe call e.preventDefault
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (semaphore) {
            onFollow(params);
        }
    }, time);
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what it is supposed to handle here. I guess i get the logic but won't handle link followed when this doesn't fire click event

Comment: Neither do I, this just captures a regular click, and if the link is followed the regular way, by redirecting, the timeout never fires.

Comment: The other handles set the semaphore to false in a short while if they run. If they do not run, then semaphore stays green. Other handles will turn red in a short while. I have suggested e.preventDefault() in a comment.